# Django throws NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. It throws such an error:

```
File "/home1/monkevco/django/django_src/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 418, in render
raise e

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$',
        register,
        { 'backend': 'lbregistration.backends.simple.SimpleBackend' },
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', profile, name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^accounts/avatar/', include('simpleavatar.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^attachments/', include('attachments.urls')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^', include('lbforum.urls')),
)
```

Update: **Django Version** `1.5`

Input Url: `http://monkev.com`

Error Location:

```
<div id="brd-head" class="gen-content">
    <p id="brd-access"><a href="#brd-main">Skip to forum content</a></p>
    <p id="brd-title"><a href="{% url lbforum_index %}">{{ LBFORUM_TITLE }}</a></p>
    <p id="brd-desc">{{ LBFORUM_SUB_TITLE }}</p>
</div>
```

Please help me figure it out. Thank you very much.

Update:

in Debug page:

```
Request URL:    http://monkev.com/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

...
...
 '/home1/monkevco/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
```

I invokes Django 1.4.1 in python path, but why the running version is Django 1.5? How to force it to 1.4.1?

Comment: Provide some template piece where you call {% url %} tag, possibly you've provided not enough or wrong parameters when inserted it into template

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko The app is not written by me, and I am so new.. would you please help me to locate the piece of code which you need? The app is `LBForum` at https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum/

Comment: It's hard to say where the error happened, because you didn't provide enough information. Maybe you can tell what URL did you open to encouter this error?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko just `http://monkev.com`

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko (1, 4, 1, 'final', 0)

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko Sorry, I have double checked and in Debug mode it shows `1.5`.

Comment: So the problem is as @Alasdair correctly mentioned, in Django version, downgrade to Django 1.4, because LBForum is not Django 1.5 compatible

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko Thank you! may I ask how to downgrade it in this issue? I googled but not found complete solution.

Comment: You better remove Django from your OS: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/#remove-any-old-versions-of-django, basically, you must just delete all django-related modules from your system.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko When I print `django.VERSION` in python, it shows `1.4.1`. Does it mean that there's an instance of Django 1.4.1 in my server? Can I invoke it without reinstall? reinstalling all the modules is a pain...it had taken me a few whole days to make them work.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko Problem updated, please.

Comment: Seems like you've removed Django improperly, make sure that old version is removed and no '.pyc' files left.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko So that I have to reinstall them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Django trunk? I would recommend running the latest release, Django 1.4.1 instead.

The `{% url %}` tag syntax is changing in Django 1.5, which means any templates which use it will have to be updated, including templates from installed apps.

Comment: I am afraid that's the problem. I have updated a few errors because of my too new version of Django. Perhaps that's just another one. I am going to try what if I downgrade the Django.

Comment: I have checked that I am using `(1, 4, 1, 'final', 0)` but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Please update your question to include the full traceback. Try load the site in debug mode - the error page will highlight the part of the template that is causing the problem. Include that in your question as well. Double check that the Django version on that debug page is 1.4.1.

Comment: In debug mode, it shows that the Django Version is `1.5`. I print django.VERSION in python and it prints `1.4.1`. How to downgrade it? I also update the error location. Please help.

Comment: Looking at the traceback, my guess is that Django 1.5 is stored in `/home1/monkevco/django/django_src`. Try removing that directory from your python path. Remember that you might need to restart Apache after making any changes.